# how to implement a jump animation in android for recycler view (following material design)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am designing an app which works on upvotes and downvotes so, my app looks even great if the animation looks like [this] https://drive.google.com/open?id=1B9MosUQR_jF-YwKR6blRqeUdENP-u78R , when a certain person gets more votes than his/her competitor.

OR

is there any library which helps me achieve this animation.

**NOTE**

All the logic for the recycler view has been coded and checked, it work's like a charm but it only needs some beauty in the form of this animation.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: i have written all the logic for the app , but have no clue on how to implement that animation in my recycler view.